# Prove that there is a sequence $j_1<j_2<j_3<\cdots$ such that for every $i$ we have $(x_{i,j_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, compactness

$x_{i,j}$, $i,j\in \Bbb N$ be real numbers bounded by $1$ i.e., $|x_{i,j}|<1$ for all $i,j \in \Bbb N$. Prove that there is a sequence $j_1<j_2<j_3<\cdots$ such that for every $i$ we have that the sequence $(x_{i,j_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent.

The way I am thinking it is that for $i=1$ we have $(x_{1,j})$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{1,j_1})$ then we will consider $(x_{2,j_1})$ which is bounded and hence have a convergent subsequence $(x_{2,j_2})$ then we will consider $(x_{3,j_2})$ and so on inductively we will choose for $i=n$ we get convergent sequence $(x_{n,j_n})$ and then if we take sequences $(x_{1,j_n}),(x_{2,j_n}), \cdots, (x_{n,j_n})$ all of them are convergent but I can't generalise it to for all $i$. Please help here.

Comment: If I understand correctly you might have your subscripts a bit mixed up.  Shouldn't the first sequences you define be $(x_{1,j_n})_n$. Also I think diagonalisation would be the way to do this.

Comment: Yes, you are right it has to be $x_{i,j_1}.$ Anyway I didn't understand the diagonalisation argument. I have to prove that $x_{i,j_n}$ is convergent for all $i$. Can you please elaborate your idea?

Comment: Yes I've posted my solution below let me know if you'd like more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following my comment here is my awnser using diagonlisation. If you've never seen this before it can be a notational nightmare and I'm sorry about that. A tip would be to write out the first few terms of sequences I define below stacked on top of one another and see where the diagonliastion comes from.

We will need **Bolzano-Weierstass**, which sates any bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence.

As you did in the first step we extract a sequence $(j_n^{(1)})_n$ such that $(x_{1,j_n^{(1)}})_n$ converges. Next notice that $(x_{2,j_n^{(1)}})_n$ is bounded and hence we can again extract a subsequence of $(j_n^{(1)})_n$ call it $(j_n^{(2)})_n$ such that $(x_{2,j_n^{(2)}})_n$ is convergent. But also note that $(x_{1,j_n^{(2)}})_n$ is convergent and converges to the same limit as $(x_{1,j_n^{(1)}})_n$  as it is a subsequence. Repeat this process indefinitely so that we a get an infinite collection of nested sequences. i.e. we get a sequence for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$,  $(j_n^{(k)})_n$ such that $(j_n^{(k+1)})_n \subset (j_n^{(k)})_n$ for all $k$. Then we can extract the "diagonal" sequence (hence the name diagonalisation) which will be precisely the sequence $(j_m^{(m)})_m$ which has tail subsequence of $(j_n^{(k)})_n$ for all $k$. By the construction of our sequences $(j_n^{(k)})_n$ it must follow that $(x_{i,j_m^{(m)}})_m$ must be convergent for all $i$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This argument works for all finite $i$, but I hesitate to say it works for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Whats to say that this construction does not produces a $j_1$ that goes to infinity as $i$ increases?

Comment: @QC_QAOA when you say $j_1$ do you mean the sequence $j^{(1)}$. If your worried about the first terms in the diagonal sequence going to infinity we need not worry as they are fixed. It's the tail of the diagonal sequence that induce the convergence and in that case we need not worry that the terms go to infinity. If the doesn't answer you're question could you please expand on it. Also this approach is a modified proof to the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem if you'd like a reference.

Comment: Finally understood. +1

Comment: Glad to hear it. The notation can be a nightmare!